# Remove substring in string and keep some substring

Tags: r, string

```
PES+PWA+PWH
```

I have the above string in R in a data frame, I have to write a script such that if it finds `PES` then it keeps `PES` and removes the rest.

I only want `PES` in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping operator in R's regex would allow removal of non-"PES" characters:

```
 gsub("(.*)(PES)(.*)", "\\2", c("PES+PWA+PWH", "something else") )
 #[1] "PES"            "something else"
```

The problem description wasn't very clear since another respondent nterpreted your request very differntly

Comment: This is twice as slow (`system.time`) as using grep

Comment: I'm not surprised. The upvote for your answer is mine. I thought it was more direct.

Comment: Hi, what if I dont want PES but want rest of the contents?

Comment: Just change the second argument from "\\2" to "\\1\\3". Read up on regular expressions in `?regex`

Answer (score 1):

```
text <- c("hello", "PES+PWA+PWH", "world")
text[grepl("PES", text)] <- "PES"
# "hello" "PES"   "world"
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question above I assumed you meant you wanted to have only those rows that contain PES?

You can use the grep function in R for that

```
column<-c("PES-PSA","PES","PWS","PWA","PES+PWA+PWH")
column[grep("PES",column)]
[1] "PES-PSA"     "PES"         "PES+PWA+PWH"
```

Grep takes the string to match as its first argument and the vector you want to match in as the second.